# картинка на не которых браузеров не отображается в чем проблема какие ошибки может быт?

Tags: браузер, кроссбраузерность, png, изображения

Есть [сайт](http://avtousta.ucoz.com/forum/) который есть в нем с верху справа рядом поиска, определение имя  страны и флаг страны, отображение флаг страны служит это [картинка](http://avtousta.ucoz.com/img/flags/flags.png), 
но почему то на браузере Гугл-хром работает отлично, но на некоторых браузерах выдает такую ошибку

[image: вот например здесь такая ошибка]

на картинке какая может быт ошибки для отображение на не которых браузеров...?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решеня... Картинка была скачана с интернета в формате **WEBP** и была переформатирована в **PNG**. Обратно переформатировал теперь нет ошибок.